# Grub2 Reboot ISO - Similar process for Mac OS Bootloader

Tags: bootcamp, startup, dual-boot, grub

I'd like to add a menu entry to the MAC OS Bootloader for a Linux ISO that resides on the harddrive. I am not looking to install a 3rd party bootloader, but do this with the bootloader MAC uses by default.

For example, on my Linux VM's I have the ISO reside on the HD and add a grub-entry for the LiveISO.

I can then use the command `grub2-reboot "LiveISO"` to reboot directly into the LiveOS without needing a USB.

Comment: I am a firm believer in a fresh reinstall of an OS Whenever there is a problem and I love live ISO for its data recovery and partition manipulation abilities

Answer (score 2):

You need startup files for your target OS.

```
1) Plug the Linux Installer on a Windows OS (It will mount the EFI partition only)
2) Copy the contents to some shared place to access it in Mac
3) Mount the EFI partition on your MAC
4) Copy the Linux startup files alongside Apple folder
```

Comment: Im sorry but this completely does not answer the question. I do not mention Ubuntu at all and a live iso does not get installed.

Comment: It’s okay, I’ve updated my answer. I’d need more details if it still doesn’t help.

Comment: The problem is this isn't really an answer at all. I don't want to use Ubuntu at all `Linux/LiveISO != Ubuntu`. I'm starting to think I need to fire up a Linux OS and use `efibootmgr` to manipulate the Mac Bootloader but I have no idea where to start and don't have the machine to test on for days and days. If you want to use Ubuntu as an example that's fine, but then give an example that works.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. This is the best I can explain or tell me a way to return your bounty.

Comment: Nah its OK, I appreciate the attempt... But if you could provide a working example for any Linux iso that would be great

Comment: It may just not be possible without grub, I'm not sure and don't have a proper test environment

Comment: I had a Ubuntu live usb which I just destroyed. When I plug it into the Mac, it doesn’t mount even through disk utility. But it shows EFI partition on windows.

Comment: U do realize I'm looking to boot an ISO directly, with grub I could just use loopback

Comment: In the EFI folder of Linux usb, there are probably three files. You can inspect your similar EFI partition on Mac to get an idea about how it works. I’ll try to paste some screenshots.

Comment: No idea what you’re talking though. What I’m suggesting is that you’ll get both OS (MAC and Linux) as startup options. You can then configure your default by simply using either option. (Just like BootCamp Windows).

Comment: Damn... I tried to regenerate the scenario and found that my answer is absolutely wrong :| sorry to waste your time. I’ll have to figure it out.